# Sed into Variable not working properly

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I am trying to strip everything except letters and delete any letters that is less than 3 characters in my bash script... I got it to delete words that has 3 characters, but other rules are not applied. Here's what I'm using:

```
name="The Man From U.N.C.L.E. Official 2 2015 Henry Cavill Armie Hammer Spy Movie AS HD"
keyword="$(sed -e 's/ [a-zA-Z]\{3\} / /g' <<< "$name")"
```

Desired output is

`echo $keyword`

shows

`The Man From Official Henry Cavill Armie Hammer Spy Movie`

any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
name="The Man From U.N.C.L.E. Official 2 2015 Henry Cavill Armie Hammer Spy Movie AS HD"
keyword="$(sed -E 's/\b(.{1,2}|[0-9]+)\b/ /g;s/ +/ /g' <<< $name)"
echo "${keyword% }"
```

Output:

```
The Man From Official Henry Cavill Armie Hammer Spy Movie
```

Comment: code above but it leaves whitespaces... how can we get rid of numbers...`2015` and just keep all words longer than 3 characters?